cannot access ResourceSource
I faced with compile error:
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /builds/my/project/src/test/java/com/some_package/MyTestClass.java:[43,40] error: cannot access ResourceSource
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

I have required import in my custom class MyTestClass.java:
import org.springframework.xml.transform.ResourceSource;

Added spring dependency to the module, but it didn't help:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-xml</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.11</version>
        </dependency>

More details:
[WARNING] COMPILATION WARNING : 
COMPILATION WARNING : 


[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING]   bad class file: C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\springframework\ws\spring-xml\4.0.11\spring-xml-4.0.11.jar(/org/springframework/xml/transform/ResourceSource.class)
  bad class file: C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\springframework\ws\spring-xml\4.0.11\spring-xml-4.0.11.jar(/org/springframework/xml/transform/ResourceSource.class)


you could try to delete your folder C:\Users\user.m2\repository\org\springframework\ws\spring-xml\ with all the files and subfolders so maven will re-download the dependency. Also did you put this dependency maybe into the <dependencyManagement> section?

Show the code, Why using such an old Spring version... What's really strange is the "bad class file." Also which JDK version, Maven version etc. do you use?

Exclude your target and .m2 folders from virus scanning. Usually, the scan of the new directories and files locks them and makes them inaccessible until they are scanned. Then, the programs that access these files fail with such "insane" messages.
